# Detect if user copied text from textfield

Tags: swift, copy, uitextfield, uipasteboard

I want to use the word that user copies from my app textfield.

I found this code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(clipboardChanged), name: UIPasteboard.changedNotification, object: nil)
```

But 'clipboardChanged' function not calling when copying text from textfield.

I use Swift 4.2

Comment: where you put this observe

Comment: @Sh_Khan in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This Code Just Worked Fine For Me:

```
    override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
        super.copy()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(clipboardChanged), name: UIPasteboard.changedNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func clipboardChanged(){
        print("Cut/Copy Performed")
    }
```

### There are many ways of achieving copy Notification

#### 1. UIMenuController

Displays a menu with Copy, Cut, Paste, Select, and Select All commands above or below the selection.

Refer:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller

https://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/

#### 2. UIResponderStandardEditActions Protocol

Responders implement methods declared in this informal protocol to handle the chosen menu commands (for example, `copy:` and `paste:`). Since your `UIViewController` inherits from `UIResponder` which indeed conforms to `UIResponderStandardEditActions`, so it will give you error saying `Redundant conformance`. So just implement the methods you need directly.

Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponderstandardeditactions

#### 3. UIPasteboard changedNotification

```
class let changedNotification: NSNotification.Name
```

This happens at the same time the pasteboard’s change count (changeCount property) is incremented. Changes include the addition, removal, and modification of pasteboard items.

Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard

Comment: Thanks for this clean answer with full detail but I don't get it how to use the 3 ways you suggested, and that above code which worked for you, did not worked for me.

Comment: I Used your code on another app & worked. my main app is a keyboard extension & I don't know why that code does not work on it.

Comment: without your code i can't predict, what's happening

Comment: You better use UIMenuController for your custom copy paste events